# Meteor: Send image as base64 to HTML

Tags: http, meteor

I want to HTTP GET an image from a URL and send the content of that request (which I think will be a base64 image) to an HTML img tag where it will serve as the src of the img. Here's what I have as one of my template helpers, but it isn't working correctly:

```
getPosterFromURL: function(posterURL) {
  return HTTP.get(posterURL, function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
      return result.content;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
},
```

Here's my img tag, just in case:

```
<img src="{{getPosterFromURL posterURL}}" class="img-responsive">
```

And a sample URL:

```
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI2NDI5ODk4N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMTI3NTE3._V1_SX300.jpg
```

It works fine if I get the base64 content of the GET request and copy-paste it into the src attribute of the img tag, but not if I try to do it using the template helper.

Note: The easy solution would be to set the URL as the src attribute of the HTML img tag but I can't do this, for various reasons.

Comment: That sample URL is presenting me a binary, not something base64 coded. Is that intended?

Comment: The sample URL points to a jpeg file. In that case, doing an `HTTP.get` is redundant, as you can just put the link into `src` attribute directly.

Comment: The API I'm getting the image from won't provide the image if it's linked to in the src of an img tag (unless I'm running the server locally) so I'm trying to get around this by using an HTTP GET request. I don't know whether it will work.

Comment: Wait ... The API behaves differently when invoked through a `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP.get` is an asynchronous call. This means that it won't block the execution of the program, instead, the execution of the remaining synchronous program will continue even before `HTTP.get` is completed and the callback is called.

```
getPosterFromURL: function(posterURL) {
    var result = // <---- called synchronously, stores 'undefined'

      HTTP.get(posterURL, function(error, result) { // <-- called asynchronously
        if (!error) {
            return result.content;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      });

    return result; // <---- called synchronously, returns 'undefined'

}
```

The way I can think of to fix this situation is to use a [`ReactiveVar`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var):

```
var myVar = new ReactiveVar(null); // initially null or some other appropriate value

var getFromURL = function(url) {
    HTTP.get(url, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
            myVar.set(result); // set the result into myVar when it is available
        }
    });
};
```

Now you can use `myVar` anywhere in your Template.helpers and when the data changes (i.e, becomes available), your view will be updated automatically.

**NOTE:** In your sample URL, the image is jpeg and not base64.

Comment: Where do I put `myVar`? Can't I put only functions in the template helpers code?

Comment: You should put `myVar` at the beginning of the file. It should be outside the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is copying the base64 payload without applying the [data: URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) appropriately. This should do:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{getPosterFromURL posterURL}}" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: I think the problem is with the callback. If I do `console.log(result.content);` before the `return result.content;` line, I see the base64 encoding of the image in the console. But if I say `var foo = HTTP.get...` then `foo` doesn't get the value I want it to get. It instead gets `undefined` when I log `foo` to the console.